# ts(2339) Error with Generic useFetchData hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a problem with my useFetchData hook when I want to make it generic. Everything is fine if there are explicit types, but after turn it into generic function, I got an error in one place: **"Property 'data' does not exist on type 'unknown'."**

Here are my types

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  avatar: string;
}

type Users = User[];

export interface People {
  page: number;
  per_page: number;
  total: number;
  total_pages: number;
  data: Users;
  support: {
    url: string;
    text: string;
  };
}
```

Here is the hook itself

```
function useFetchData<DataType, ResponseType>(
  url: string
): {
  dataX: DataType | null;
  done: boolean;
} {
  const [dataX, setDataX] = useState<DataType | null>(null);
  const [done, setDone] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(({ data }: ResponseType) => { //here is the error
        setDataX(data);
        setDone(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return {
    dataX,
    done,
  };
}

function CustomHookComponent() {
  const { dataX, done } = useFetchData<Users, People>(
    'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
  );

  return (/*some stuff*/)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript that `ResponseType` has a `data` property which you do with [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)

So your function declaration would be something like:

```
function useFetchData<DataType, ResponseType extends {data: DataType}>(
  url: string
): {
  dataX: DataType | null;
  done: boolean;
} {
  // more code here
}
```